# Re-setting field value with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('#name1').focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'start value') {
        console.log($(this).val()); // this prints "start value"
        $(this).val() == ''
    }
```

What I am trying to do is when a user focuses on the text input `#name1`, the field's value will disappear. However, the above does nothing, and the text value stays the same. Why is this occurring and what do I need to change?

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to create a placeholder... if so, why not just use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute, and one of the various existing [polyfills](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#name1').focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'start value') {
        console.log($(this).val()); // this prints "start value"
        $(this).val("");
    }
```

You must write assigning value in parentheses like this `$(this).val("");`

Answer (score 1):

`this.val()` is a function which should be called like `$(this).val('new value')` to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

To assign a value use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) it like this:

```
$(this).val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
 `$(this).val() == ''` 
try 
`$(this).val('');`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the html5 placeholder attribute with something like modernizr for older browser support that way your not writing a crap ton of those functions you instead could just do placeholder="your text" and achieve the same effect.